# java8 make immutable List after removing null elements

Tags: arraylist, java-8, immutability

I know `Arrays.asList` creates immutable `List`. My requirement is to create immutable `List<Student>` with no `null` elements in it. So I am creating `new ArrayList()` first then removing `null` elements using java 8 `filters` as shown below:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(makeStudent("ram", 'M'));
list.add(makeStudent("sathya", 'F'));
list.add(makeStudent(null, 'M'));
list.add(makeStudent("sri", 'M'));

list = list.stream().filter(s -> s != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Below is the `makeStudent` method, it returns `null` if name is not available:

```
private Student makeStudent(String name, char gender) {
    return null != name ? new Student(name, gender) : null;
}
```

I thought `Collectors.toList()` will create immutable. But I was wrong. The `list` is still mutable here. Is there a better way to make the `list` clean (remove `null`) and immutable in single line using `java 8`?

Comment: Note: `Arrays.asList` does not create an immutable list. You can't add or remove elements (which would change the size, and arrays can't change size). However, you can still **set** individual elements.

Comment: @StuartMarks thanks for your information.. its something I am not aware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) to wrap the `List` collected by the stream.

```
list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list.stream()
                                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

the `Collectors.toList()` method do the things like as reduce:

```
//pseudo-code
Collectors.reduce(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll)
```

**IF** you passing an immutable `List` to reduce you can't collect any items from the stream into the `List` since it is immutable.

Answer (score 5):

You might rewrite your code to this one:

```
list = list.stream()
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
```

Collector [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) allow you to wrap result collection

Answer (score 1):

Even though you specified Java 8, here is how you can filter an existing `List` into a fully **immutable** `List` that you're looking for with Java 9:

```
list = list.stream()
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(List::of));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use `Collections.unmodifiableList` as suggested in other answers or you can also convert stream to array and then use `Arrays.asList`.

```
list = Arrays.asList(list.stream()
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .toArray(Student[]::new));
```

Comment: is it creating and passing `new` Student array to `Arrays.asList`? Little worried about creation of arrays.

Comment: The list you get from `Arrays.asList()` is modifiable, so you would still need to wrap it in `Collections.unmodifiableList()` or similar if you need it to be unmodifiable.

Comment: @Sridhar, `Collectors.toList()` also creates an array (at least one) behind the scenes, so I wouldn’t be that worried.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes you are right. But I thought in the question OP wanted the resultant list to behave like `Arrays.asList()` (which can not grow or shrink)